# How do I work with "image data as a byte string", using Python?

Tags: python, image, pygame, byte

First I'm going to explain what I'm trying to do and then explain my problem.

Okay so I've been making prototypes on a project that I hope to be working on over the summer. The project is a small media player and one of the requirements is to display the albulm artwork of an mp3 file.

After some research I found this library:
http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/

The reason I chose this library was because it doesn't have any dependencies and it would make my application more portable.

After fidilling around with the code I was able to retrieve data from the mp3 file, such as the artist and recording year etc. I'll give a little demonstration here:

```
from mutagen.mp3 import MP3
audio = MP3("born.mp3")
artist = audio["TPE1"]
print artist
```

In case this doesn't make much sense, this is the tutorial that is provided by mutagen - http://code.google.com/p/mutagen/wiki/Tutorial (its a little bit short)

Problem - I want to display the image using pygame. Normally this would read something like this:

```
 monkey = pygame.image.load("monkey.jpg")

 screen.blit(monkey,(0,0))
```

but instead I want to do use the image from the image file. So going from the first example it reads something like:

```
audio = MP3("born.mp3")
data = audio.tags['APIC:'].data
monkey = pygame.image.load(data)
```

but pygame throws an exception error because the data type of the variable 'value' is raw image data as a byte string.

Question - Is it possible to convert the byte string to some sort of image format so pygame can use it?

For python documentation on images - http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/image.html

I'm not sure if it is even possible to do what I am asking so please forgive me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `pygame.image.fromstring()`?

note: since it's raw data, you'll need to know in advance a few details such as the resolution and colour depth.

Comment: Hi, I was trying that but I kept getting errors so I wasn't sure if I was on the right track. Can you give me an example? Thanks

Comment: i'll try to remember to look into it later.. i don't have an mp3 file with embedded image data on me, and i don't have pygame installed either.  

i can say that PIL (python-imaging) and matplotlib would be my first choice for what you're doing though:
import Image;
from matplotlib import pyplot as p;
im = Image.fromstring((w,h), 'RGB', data);
p.imshow(im);
p.show()